# file html link to a shared folder doesnt work

Tags: html, security

Hi I have a html link that contains a link to a shared folder, this link works perfectly on my localhost but when I change to a production server goes down, my code is this:

```
<a href='file://somesharedfolder/anotherfolder'>link to folder</a>
```

I think it may perhaps be a browser security problem, but I am not sure, any ideas?

Thank you very much.

Comment: First, you have a syntax error (closing `'` missing). Second, according to the `file` URI protocol, the `somesharedfolder` would actually be the server’s host name (if omitted, `localhost` is assumed). I’m surprised that it worked for you. Also note, that the client resolves the `file` URI.

Comment: somesharedfolder is the name of the shared folder, when I say localhost, is because it is a war that is in a glassfish server that contains a jsp which has the url to the shared folder, when I put this in a production environment jsp the link stops working . thank you!

Comment: I found the answer, IE does not allow this type of links, when it detects that it is a localhost allow such links to be within the same machine. To achieve this kind of links are allowed on a server that is not a localhost you need to go to the IE security options and add our domain as a safe site, doing this as you can access the link without problem. Thank you all for your responses.

Answer (score 1):

On production side your base url is your hostname

Try doing this

```
<a href='http://www.yourwebsiteurl.com/somesharedfolder/anotherfolder>link to folder</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Modern browsers prevent linking to `file:` scheme URIs from `http:` URIs.

Serve all your content over HTTP instead.

Comment: I've been thinking that, my question was why when deploy my component in a local server the url localhost it worked, maybe somehow the browser detects that you are on a local server and therefore allows, I dont understand how it works this part

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, IE does not allow this type of links, when it detects that it is a localhost allow such links to be within the same machine. To achieve this kind of links are allowed on a server that is not a localhost you need to go to the IE security options and add our domain as a safe site, doing this as you can access the link without problem. Thank you all for your responses.